# Adding test suite instead of test case in BOOST TEST

Tags: c++, testing, boost, boost-test

I have taken over some BOOST TEST code which has been written as a static test setup for testing media files. However, the requirement is to make the test setup dynamic, as the number of media files to be tested can vary over time, i.e. one day there could be 3 files and the next day there could be 15 files to be tested.

The current setup uses a number of BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE's to build the static tree structure, and my problem is that when I come to the point in the test tree where I would like to add 2 test_suite's TestSuiteD1 and TestSuiteD2 to the test tree in order to run my dynamic tests, I am only able to add 2 test_case's in that location, and is therefore unable to add further test_case's (TestCase1 - TestCase3) below this tree element. I have been searching the Internet for a ::make_test_suite version, of the below ::make_test_case, but with no luck:

static boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar TestSuiteD1_registrar0
          ( boost::unit_test::make_test_case(&fTestSuiteD1_invoker , "TestSuiteD1" ),
           boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_tc_exp_fail::instance()->value() );

I have added some example code below to show what I would like to do, and to get some feedback if it is possible to add a test_suite instead of a test_case:

```
class MyTestSuite : public TestFixture1 {
    public:
    static void TestCase1() { //Some test };
    static void TestCase2() { //Some test };
    static void TestCase3() { //Some test };

    test_suite* TestThis(string a, string b, string d)
        test_suite* tsE = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "TestSuiteE" );
        tsE->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &TestCase1 ) );
        tsE->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &TestCase2 ) );
        tsE->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &TestCase3 ) );
    };
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuiteA );
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE( TestSuiteB , TestFixture1 );
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuiteC );
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuiteD );

    static test_unit* TestSuiteD1_invoker (void) { 
        MyTestSuite MyTS;
        MyTS.TestThis("a" , "b" , "D1" );
        return 0;
    }
    struct TestSuiteD1_id {};

    static boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar
      TestSuiteD1_registrar0 ( boost::unit_test
      ::make_test_case(&fTestSuiteD1_invoker , "TestSuiteD1" ),
      boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_tc_exp_fail<TestSuiteD1_id
      >::instance()->value() ); 

    static test_unit* TestSuiteD2_invoker (void) { 
        MyTestSuite MyTS;
        MyTS.TestThis("a" , "b" , "D2" );
        return 0;
    }
    struct TestSuiteD2_id {};

    static boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar TestSuiteD2_registrar0
      ( boost::unit_test::make_test_case(&fTestSuiteD2_invoker , "TestSuiteD2" ),
      boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_tc_exp_fail<TestSuiteD2_id
      >::instance()->value() ); 

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() 
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if fixtures are the right way to go. Have a look at [BOOST_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-test-case-template.html)

```
BOOST_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION( my_test, T )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( sizeof(T), 4 );
}

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    typedef boost::mpl::list<int,long,unsigned char> test_types;

    framework::master_test_suite().
        add( BOOST_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE( my_test, test_types ) );

    return 0;
}
```